# Asterisk - best practice to play multiple sound files in .call files

Tags: asterisk

I have trouble with playing multiple sound files (.wav) in .call files.
I pass a lots of sound files in variable (SetVar: Sound=custom/1_Messages0201&custom/20c&...) 
The problem is string size. When size is smaller than 240 characters, all sound files play correctly. All files after 240 th character are trimmed, and appears error

```
pbx_spool.c: Syntax error at line 10 of /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/333.call
```

I was reading for limitation  for dial string lenght

> Note: Up until and including Asterisk 1.2 the length of the Dial string cannot exceed about 240 characters (any exceeding characters will be truncated). This limitation has been removed in Asterisk 1.4, unless you have set LOW_MEMORY in the compile options.

Is there any way to remove this limitation, or to increase dial string size.
Maybe anyone can suggest me any other better idea.

Asterisk version:

```
Asterisk 11.2.1 built by root @ ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX on a x86_64 running Linux
```

Dial plan:

```
exten =>    123,1,AGI(monitor.php,outgoing,Outgoing_UNLIMITED,${CALLERID(num)},${EXTEN},Set(CALLERID (num)=XXXXXXXXX))
exten => 123,1,Dial(SIP/6845987568/${EXTEN:0},30,T)
exten => 123,2,Set(CDR(userfield)=${NumberDialed})
exten => 123,3,Playback(${Sound})
```

Call file:

```
Channel: SIP/XXXXX/XXXXXX
CallerID: XXXXXXX
MaxRetries: 2
RetryTime: 15
Context: XXXXXX
Extension: 123
Priority: 1
Account: XXXXXX
SetVar:    Sound=custom/1_Messages0201&custom/20c&custom/i&custom/1om&custom/March&custom/2c&custom/hiliadi&custom/i&custom/13of&custom/godina&custom/1_Messages0202&custom/3c&custom/3c&custom/3c&custom/3c&custom/3c&custom/3c&custom/3c&custom/3c&custom/1_Messages0203&custom/200c&custom/50c&custom/i&custom/6c&custom/leva&custom/i&custom/70c&custom/i&custom/8c&custom/stotinki&custom/1_Messages0204
SetVar: NumberDialed=XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After call file fire you ALSO will have same issue in your dialplan(it also have limit). Playback application is not designed to play alot of different files. If you need do that, you have do that by dialplan.

You can  send it like this:

```
Setvar: file_max=2
Setvar: file1=custom/1_message
Setvar: file2=custom/2_message
```

After that use asterisk's dialplan to play files one-by-one. For example like this:

```
exten => 123,3,Set(i=0);
exten => 123,n(loop),Set(i=$[ ${i} + 1 ])
exten => 123,n,GotoIF($[ $i > ${file_max} ]?exit)
exten => 123,n,Playback(${file${i}})
exten => 123,n,Goto(loop)
exten => 123,n(exit),Noop(end)
```

Note, there will be alot of other issues with this task, i recomend you check opensource dialler code like vicidial or hire expert.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem is to set a "campaign" call variable, and then define the various "campaigns" in a DB.  I then use a DB look up in the dial plan to get the list of sound files.  I have my DBGet Ruby script return two values;  a "more files" flag and a list of up to ten sound files.  I loop the DBGet and keep playing sets of file to the customer as long as the "more files" flag is true.

It works like a charm.  And keeps the call files -much- easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We plan to execute hundreds of call files with a lots of sound files. I thing that, connection to DB can delay execution of the .call files

Comment: So keep a local replica of the DB on your PBX.  That's pretty much an instant look up.  A modern multicore PBX server's enemy is transcoding calls, not localhost netwok IO.